# Delete Archive log file

Tags: oracle-11g, rman

I am using oracle database 11g. Some day's back we have deleted our Archivelog Manually, and now it's getting full and due to that we are not able to connect to our database.

So how should i delete archivelog files :

Is there any way by which we can delete archivelog through rman without connecting to the target database.

Or can we increase the archivelog disk space.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi Sham, you really need to get some training on Oracle, or spend a couple days (at the very least) reading the admin guide. You're setting yourself up for major disasters if you don't understand how the database works.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting archivelog data would normally be done as part of the backup operation removing older archive data after a new backup is taken.

You should read the following:

- [Oracle Concepts Guide (pdf)](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_pdf?pathname=server.112/e25789.pdf), particularly chapter 11
- [Administrator's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494.pdf), chapter 13 (which has useful information on Archive Logs).

Only after reading all that should you look at the Backup and Recovery guides section on Configuring an Archived Redo Log Deletion Policy. I purposely did not provide a direct link.  When you are ready, you can lookup the book in the [Master Book List](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/portal.all_books#index-BAC).